# Coding Bat Exercise BMIResult

Tags: java

I am new to coding and am having issues with this problem any help is appreciated.

Here is the problem.

Given an individual's height in inches and weight in pounds, calculate their BMI. BMI is calculated as BMI = (weight*703)/(height*height) Then, based on their BMI, if it is less than 18.5, return a message that says "You are underweight." If it is at least and not more than 26, return a message that says "Your weight is healthy." If it is 26 or more, return a message that says "You are overweight."

BMIResult(177, 69) → "You are overweight."

BMIResult(125, 62) → "Your weight is healthy."

BMIResult(95, 64) → "You are underweight."

Hint: Round your BMI calculation to one decimal place. Be sure the message return is exactly as displayed.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG!!  This is the Error I am getting.

Error:  public String BMIResult(double weight,double height) {

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This method must return a result of type String

Possible problem: the if-statement structure may theoretically 
allow a run to reach the end of the method without calling return.
Consider adding a last line in the method return some_value; 
so a value is always returned.

HERE IS MY CODE THAT GETS THE ERROR MESSAGE ABOVE:

```
public String BMIResult(double weight,double height) {
double bmi=((weight*703)/(height*height));

if (BMI<18.5)

  return "You are underweight.";

if (BMI>18.5 && BMI<26)

  return "Your weight is healthy.";

if (BMI>=26)

  return "You are overweight.";



}
```

Even if I try to convert from a double to a string it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't handle the BMI == 18.5 case, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `else`, the compiler does not know that one of your current conditions must evaluate to `true` (because as posted they are all independent and unconnected statements).

```
public String BMIResult(double weight,double height) {
  double bmi=((weight*703)/(height*height));
  if (BMI<18.5) {
    return "You are underweight.";
  } else if (BMI<26) { // BMI>=18.5 not needed, or the first if would be entered.
    return "Your weight is healthy.";
  } else { // <-- you might omit this else entirely, and end the method
    return "You are overweight."; // <-- with this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version:

```
public class BMI {

    public String calculateBMI(double weight, double height) {
        double bmi = ((weight * 703) / (height * height));

        if (bmi < 18.5) {
            return "You are underweight.";
        }
        if (bmi < 26) {
            return "Your weight is healthy.";
        }

        return "You are overweight.";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new BMI().calculateBMI(95, 64));
    }
}
```

Problems with your original code are the name of the variable `bmi` and a lack of a return statement if none of the ifs are executed. In fact that situation (pretty much) cannot happen but the compiler isn't clever enough to know that.

Also, there is no need to perform many of the checks you were making because they logically must automatically be true if the previous `if` statement failed. Similarly, the last `if` is not needed since if the execution has reached this point the person is clearly overweight.

In Java there are naming-conventions, such as a methods always start with lowercase characters. I have renamed your `BMIResult()` method as `calculateBMI()`. Although, many people would encourage you to write `calculateBmi()` as that's more inline with modern style.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, if neither of the conditions are satisfied, nothing will be returned.

Use :

```
public String BMIResult(double weight,double height) {
double bmi=((weight*703)/(height*height));

if (BMI<18.5)

  return "You are underweight.";

if (BMI>18.5 && BMI<26)

  return "Your weight is healthy.";

if (BMI>=26)

  return "You are overweight.";

return ""; //add something.


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know that your code will execute the code of one of your if statements. You must have a return at the end of all the if's or just write an else at the end.